# How to do addition and division of aliased columns in a query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I am trying to do some basic math in some basic queries. I need to add up wins, losses, total, and percentages.  I usually ask for the raw numbers and then do the calculations once I return my query to page.  I would like to give SQL Server the opportunity to work a little harder.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT   SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
         SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses,
         TotalWins + TotalLosses as TotalPlays,
         TotalPlays / TotalWins  as PctWins
```

Here's what I am doing now:

```
SELECT   SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
         SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses,
         SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) + SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Votes
```

What is the easiest, cleanest way to do simple math calculations like this in a query?

**EDIT: **

While I got some great answers, I didn't get what I was looking for.

The scores that I will be calculating are for a specific team,  so, my results need to be like this:

```
TeamID   Team    Wins   Losses  Totals
1        A's     5      3       8
2        Bee's   7      9       16
3        Seas    1      3       4

SELECT   T.TeamID,
         T.Team,
         V.TotalWins,
         V.TotalLosses,
         V.PctWins
FROM     Teams T 

      JOIN 

     SELECT  V.TeamID,
             SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as V.TotWin,
             SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as V.TotLoss
     FROM    Votes V
GROUP BY V.TeamID
```

I tried a bunch of things, but don't quite know what wrong.  I am sure the JOIN part is where the problem is though.  How do I bring these two resultsets together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to wrap your query in an external one:

```
SELECT TotalWins,
       TotalLosses,
       TotalWins + TotalLosses as TotalPlays,
       TotalPlays / TotalWins  as PctWins
FROM
( SELECT SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
         SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses
  FROM ...
)
```

Another way (suggested by [@Mike Christensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392044/mike-christensen)) is to use [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
; WITH Calculation AS 
    ( SELECT SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
             SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses
      FROM ...
    )

SELECT TotalWins,
       TotalLosses,
       TotalWins + TotalLosses as TotalPlays,
       TotalPlays / TotalWins  as PctWins
FROM
       Calculation
```

---

Sidenote: No idea if this would mean any preformance difference in SQL-Server but you can also write these sums:

```
SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

as counts:

```
COUNT(case when vote = 1 then 1 end)    --- the ELSE NULL is implied
```

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a whirl.

Comment: What I did to simply things was `SELECT *, colA / colB, colA + colB FROM (SELECT ...` so that I didn't have to manually specify all the columns from the inner select and only the "derived" values

Answer (score 4):

try

```
select a, b, a+b as total
from (
  select
    case ... end as a,
    case ... end as b
  from realtable
) t
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, this is the code you put forward with corrections to the syntax:

```
SELECT   
    T.TeamID,
    T.Team,
    V.TotalWins,
    V.TotalLosses,
    PctWins  =  V.TotalWins * 100 / CAST(V.TotalWins + V.TotalLosses AS float)
FROM Teams T 
JOIN  (
    SELECT  
        TeamID,
        SUM(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
        SUM(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses
    FROM Votes
    GROUP BY TeamID
    ) as V on T.TeamID = V.TeamID
```

Note the brackets around the inner select.

Answer (score 2):

It might help you if you're doing this sort of thing more than once to create a view...

```
CREATE VIEW [Totals]
SELECT   
    SUM(case when T.vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalWins,
    SUM(case when T.vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLosses,
    T.SomeGroupColumn
FROM SomeTable T
GROUP BY T.SomeGroupColumn
```

Comment: Btw. I do prefer the CTE answer listed already if you want to solve this as a one off rather than reusable.